# Rendering file with MIME Type in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, mime-types

Here's the code:

```
render :file => @somedir + "/blah.xml"
```

...but the resulting MIME type is text/html when I check in FireBug. How do I specify a MIME type in this case?

Answer (score 35):

Actually there are two ways to set the content-type (I think this is what you mean by mime-type). You should use the second option, if it works for your Rails version.

```
class FileController < ApplicationController

  def index
    filename = 'some.xml'

    extname = File.extname(filename)[1..-1]
    mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(extname)
    content_type = mime_type.to_s unless mime_type.nil?

    # 1
    #headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
    #render :file => filename

    # 2
    render :file => filename, :content_type => content_type
  end

end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alternative way of getting mime type from a file name/path `MIME::Types.type_for("some.xml").first.content_type`

Answer (score 16):

```
render :file => @somedir + "/blah.xml", :content_type => Mime::XML
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"
```

? Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html).  Basically you need to use render :xml => blah.to_xml

Comment: Thanks, but the request has no extension, and I think responds_to uses the extension to determine the format. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html, you could specify it like so:

```
render file: @somedir + "/blah.xml", mime_type: Mime::Type.lookup("text/xml")
```