# How to get Rails to serve my dynamic Greasemonkey script with the proper MIME type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, greasemonkey, mime-types, content-type

I have a static Greasemonkey script and it works fine.
I have a rails 4 application, and I just want to customize my script for current user.
My problem is I can render the script named `script.user.js`, but the content type is always text/html and Greasemonkey can't detect it for install.

Here few lines of code :

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
    get 'script.user.js', :action => 'script', :on => :collection
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def script
    render file: 'users/script.user.js', content_type: "application/x-javascript"
end
```

How do I get my app to serve this file with the right type?

Comment: Thank you for Edit and the link !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (untested):

```
def script
    render file: 'users/script.user.js', content_type: Mime::JS
end
```

---

Similar problem and answers: "[Rendering file with MIME Type in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299999/331508)".

Also, from OP comment (I should have remembered this):  Clear your browser cache to let the new association take effect.

Comment: Thank you ! This work ! At the end, my first code worked too, it seems I needed to clear recent history of my browser... Anyway, my solution, your solution and your link works perfectly ! Thanks again !